# Filling an array in Java. (For sequence alignment)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to fill a 2 dimension array, using an algorithm inspired by the [Needleman-Wunsch](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Needleman-Wunsch) dynamic-programming algorithm for sequence alignment:

- choice 1 :  `[ i-1 ][ j-1 ] + (string1.charAt(i-1) == string2.charAt(j-1)?2:-1`
- choice 2 :  `[ i-1 ][ j ] + penality` (which is equal to -1)
- choice 3 :  `[ i ][ j-1 ] + penality` (same as above)

`[ i ][ j ] = max (choice1, choice2, choice3)`

Example for `string1 = attga` and `string2 = cttga`
with first row and col initialized to `0 -> - i` (length of the row)

I'm supposed to get :

```
         a  t  t  g  a
      0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
   c -1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
   t -2 -2  1  3  2  1
   t -3 -3  3  5  7  6
   g -4 -4  2  2  9  11
   a -5 -5  1  3  8  13
```

So i coded this in java :

```
int i,j, gap = -1, choix1, choix2, choix3; 


    for(i = 0; i <= seq1.length(); i++){
        matrice[i][0] = i * gap;
    }

    for(j = 0; j <= seq2.length(); j++){
        matrice[0][j] = j * gap;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= seq1.length(); i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= seq2.length(); j++){

                choix1 = matrice[i-1][j-1] + (seq1.charAt(i-1)==seq2.charAt(j-1)?2:-1);
                choix2 = matrice[i-1][j] + gap;
                choix3 = matrice[i][j-1] + gap;
                matrice[i][j] = Math.max(Math.max(choix1, choix2),choix3);

        }
    }
```

and it results in this matrix :

```
 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
-1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -2
-2 -2  1  0 -1 -2
-3 -3  0  3  2  1
-4 -4 -1  2  5  4
-5 -5 -2  1  4  7
```

and it is wrong, but i can't find the reason. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: In the code you've posted, you're using `seq1.charAt(i1)` rather than `seq1.charAt(i1 - 1)`. That should be resulting in an IndexOutOfBoundsException, since your iterator is 1-based and continues until the length of the sequence, inclusive.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is my bad, it is:
    
    seq1.charAt(i-1);

Comment: Did @AndyThomas comment resolved your issue ?

Comment: No, his comment solved a miss-type i did when editing here.

Comment: @Bouji - In the matrix you're "supposed to get," how would those 3's nearest the upper-left be computed for any pair of sequences? Is there an error in that first matrix? If you've chosen choice 2 or 3, there should be a gap penalty -- -3-1 = -4, or 1-1 = 0. If you've chosen choice 1, the value should be -2 + 2 = 0. Your matrix shows zero.

Comment: Found the problem, i inverted the column and row, and took everytime choice1 when chartAt(-1) == charAt(j-1).  Problem resolved.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, that in second row you've got -2, which is true in this case but would be not if `string1= cttga` and `string2 = attga`. 
Anyway provide an answer and mark resolved, so no one else will break head over this problem :]

Comment: @Bouji so post your solution as an answer... telling what was wrong with your code

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that i inverted the column and row, also for choice1, i chosed it everytime when:
seq1.charAt(i-1) == seq2.char(j-1) without taking in fact the max statement.

Problem solved.